# React: ref is not a prop

Tags: reactjs

When using React.js

Why do I get `` `ref` is not a prop `` & `` `key` is not a prop. `` error

Notes

- however I do not get this error running with webpack-dev-server.
- I do not have `ref` or `key` defined in any of my react components.

Answer (score 23):

Check this out: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/5744

`ref` and `key` are reserved prop names in React, and are used internally. That's why you are getting this warning.

If you want to use `ref`, use `this.refs.yourinput`

Comment: I do not have ref or key defined in any of my react components.

Comment: Some the libraries u are importing might be having these

Comment: This error is also shown if you are using prop-types and have added ref as a PropType

Comment: I don't understand why can't React check if the `ref` prop is a "real" `ref` and allow it, instead of manually wrapping the component with `forwardRef`.. it's very tedious. Automictic detection would seem better